# How to access "loaded" attribute of aura:iteration while it is still false?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

Whenever I try to get "loaded" attribute of aura:iteration, I get it as true. I want a time when it is false, i.e when iteration is not complete, and during that time do action like show spinner or anything else. Can anybody help me how can I access it in markup(component) or in controller?

Code:

```
<aura:iteration aura:id="iterationID" var="setting" items="{!v.customSetting}">
  <tr>
    <aura:iteration var="fieldName" items="{!v.fieldAPINamesList}">
      <td >
        <div class="slds-truncate">
          <c:CustomSettingValue setting="{!setting}" fieldName="{!fieldName}" settingType="{!v.settingType}"/>
        </div> 
      </td>
    </aura:iteration>
  </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

If there are multiple records, i.e if iteration is too long, component rendering is taking time and during that time I want to show a spinner. To stop spinner, I need to know that iteration is complete and hence was looking for when the "loaded" attribute becomes true, I could stop spinner.

UPDATE:

IN console, giving error for each outer iteration:

> WARNING: Performance degradation: Multiple items were set in iteration[id:1:9974;a]in the same Aura cycle.

Comment: I'd assume it's always true because you are reading the loaded property after the iteration is complete (for example in the following frame). Are you building a list of data? Do you have a code sample?

Comment: "Loading" is nigh instantaneous. Do you mean you want to show a spinner while you're getting data from the server? If so, you might want to look at aura:waiting and aura:doneWaiting.

Comment: @sfdcfox : I am not getting data from server. I am rendering a new component per iteration. Please find code updated

Comment: Why would each component take so long to render if it's not getting something from the server? It should be instantaneous as sfdcfox said. Also having a nested iteration for your purpose is suspicious, this means you can have variable columns and variable rows. This will not look right if the num of columns changes. Back to the loading issue, from a high level approach you should inform the parent component each time a `customSettingValue` is done loading, and count against how many you have vs how many are done loading and then hide the spinner. But they shouldn't take long to load.

Comment: For the spinner issue, thanks for the idea!!...I will surely try and let you know.

I am able to handle dynamic columns and rows properly. I think it is slow probably due to large number of components getting rendered. Say I have customSetting.length=15 and fieldAPINamesList.length=10, then I have 150 commponents to be loaded, which probably is a bit heavy for processor to load at one go.

Comment: It depends on how complex your customSettingValue component is, but 150 is not a lot of components to render at all. In a typical aura application view you might easily be looking at a thousand components.

Comment: ok!! so probably I need to look in the component and check its complexity...Thanks for the help.

Also, the spinner is working better than before now

Comment: @citizen conn: I checked the child component and it has about 10 attributes, 10 helper methods, handles 2 events and registers 2 events, has 6 controller methods and has 5 <div> tags which are toggled hidden as per action. It aso has 1 aura:iteraion which is rendered conditionally. There is no aura:if. Also, I checked the lighting inspector. It gives me idle time 29% and 0.05% or so for other elements like aura:html etc. Should this be considered as a complex component?